Customize AisHierarchicalMenu refine behavior when deselecting a child facet
The default behavior of the AisHierarchicalMenu is that, when a parent facet is chosen, then a child is chosen, and then that child is deselected, both the parent and the child facets are cleared– clearing the entire search query.
Tooling
I'm using Vue InstantSearch w/the Options API.
https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/hierarchical-menu/vue/
Expected behavior
Users would expect that parent category to be maintained when only "toggling off" the nested/child category.
Question
Is there a way to override the default refine() behavior in order to allow for that behavior, as opposed to the default? I believe that I'd need to customize the component, but am trying to avoid creating an entirely unique component.

I've tried customizing the params passed to the refine() function, but it seems that the refine() toggles the parent no matter the param passed to it.

